# Does 'erase all content and settings' actually erase all data?

Tags: iphone, data

I recently decided to sell two of my iPhone's (5 and 6s) and I used the 'erase all content and settings' option to wipe and factory reset my iPhone. Now, I'm a little concerned whether this is enough to prevent any data retrieval on my iPhone's and I was wondering if a simple reset in iPhone's settings can provide the same effects as that of an overwritten data? If not, what should I do? Is there a method for overwriting data on an iPhone as there is for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you follow the [steps provided by Apple to erase your iOS device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351), it will erase all data on the device.  A simple 'reset' of the device is not the same as 'erase all contents and settings'.

### Follow these steps:

1. If you paired an Apple Watch with your iPhone, unpair your Apple Watch.
2. Back up your device.
3. Sign out of iCloud and the iTunes & App Store.

   - If you're using iOS 10.3 or later, tap `Settings > [your name]`. Scroll down and tap `Sign Out`. Enter your Apple ID password and tap `Turn Off`.
   - If you're using iOS 10.2 or earlier, tap `Settings > iCloud > Sign Out`. Tap `Sign Out` again, then tap `Delete from My [device]` and enter your Apple ID password. Then go to `Settings > iTunes & App Store > Apple ID > Sign Out`.
4. Go back to Settings and tap `General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings`. If you turned on `Find My iPhone`, you might need to enter your Apple ID and password.
5. If asked for your device passcode or Restrictions passcode, enter it. Then tap `Erase [device]`.
6. If you're switching to a non-Apple phone, [deregister iMessage](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203042).
7. Contact your carrier for help transferring service to a new owner. If you aren't using a SIM card with your device, you can contact them to get help transferring service to the new owner.

Comment: Just to add onto this, yes it will erase all data effectively–you don't need to overwrite it or anything like that.

Comment: @EzekielElin Yes, isn't that what I indicated in my answer?

Comment: Oddly enough a few times I have wiped some work-purchased and returned iPhones. These are phones with disabled SIM cards (Via AT&T) but after the reboot and going through the setup procedure there was a red dot over the phone.app icon indicating a number of voicemails were there. They did not exist on the phone and you couldn't make a call to retrieve them from AT&T and another trip through "erase all content and settings" did nothing. So god only knows what was going on, perhaps a bug in an older version of iOS but still damn strange.